# RemoteViews setInt setImageResource not working in a ImageButton

Tags: android, widget, imagebutton

I'm developing a button widget, when user click on the button i want to change the resource image, but it's not working, there is my code :

widget.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/widgetButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/android_widget"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/widget_image"
            />

</FrameLayout>
```

MyWidgetActivity.java :

```
public class MyWidgetActivity extends Activity implements ExceptionHandler {

    RemoteViews remoteViews;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ... 

        // Get the remoteViews view
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        // Change the remoteViews button clicked style
        remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widgetButton, "setImageResource",
                R.drawable.android_widget2);

    }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem using selector :

I added this widget_selector.xml file on drawable folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/android_widget2" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/android_widget2" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/android_widget" />

</selector>
```

Then i referred it in my ImageButton background attribute like this :

```
android:background="@drawable/widget_selector"
```

It works like a charm, with 0 line of code !

Comment: XML _is_ code, so saying 0 line of code is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the remoteViews view
remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
// Change the remoteViews button clicked style
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widgetButton, "setImageResource", R.drawable.android_widget2);

//......For update AppWidget
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetID, remoteViews);
```

Comment: MyWidgetActivity - is config activity for widget or no?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by config activity but MyWidgetActivity show some view on screen when user click on the widget button, this works perfectly but i want also to change the button style when it's clicked..